difference quotient for higher order derivative
Exercise 1 on p.29 of Series Approximation Methods in Statistics by John E. Kolassa:

[Show] that if $f_0(\beta)$ is a function with $n$ derivatives on an interval containing $0$, and $f_k(\beta)$ is defined recursively by
$$
f_k(\beta) = \frac{f_{k-1}(\beta) - f_{k-1}(-\beta)}{2\beta}
$$
then the derivative of order $n$ of $f_0$ at $0$ is $\lim_{\beta\to 0} f_n(\beta)$.

For the $k=1$ case I get
$$
f_1(-\beta) = \frac{f_{k-1}(-\beta) - f_{k-1}(\beta)}{-2\beta} 
= f_1(\beta), 
$$
so that for all $k\ge 2$, $f_k(\beta)\equiv 0$ when $\beta\neq 0$. Am I making a mistake or is there a typo in the problem statement?
